# how to display a loading visual when waiting on related models to load with emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the best way to hook into a `hasMany` relationships loading promise in ember data? This is not the primary model so a loading route isn't relevant. I already have the main model, `Project`, loaded and my template displays its related `RequestMatchers`. It's the `RequestMatchers` i'd like to set a property on the `ProjectController` or something to display a loading visual queue. This is what i have currently.

/models/project.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    private: DS.attr('boolean'),
    requestMatchers: DS.hasMany('request-matcher', {async: true}),
    responses: DS.hasMany('response', {async: true})
});
```

/templates/project.hbs

```
{{#each matcher in requestMatchers}}
 //render requestMatchers
{{/each}}
```

I'd like to do something like this but i don't know how to hook into that async request for the `RequestMatchers` promise.

```
{{#if requestMatchersLoading}}
    Loading request matchers...
{{/if}}

{{#each matcher in requestMatchers}}
 //render requestMatchers
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isFulfilled` flag

```
{{#if requestMatchers.isFulfilled}}
  {{#each matcher in requestMatchers}}
     //render requestMatchers
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
   Loading request matchers...
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't depend on [`isFulfilled`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html#property_isFulfilled) as it only becomes true if loading succeeds. Use [`isPending`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html#property_isPending) instead.

You can also check [`isRejected`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html#property_isRejected) and add a reload button if needed.

```
{{#if isFulfilled}}
  Done loading.
{{else}}
  {{#if isPending}}
    Loading...
  {{else}}
    Restart!
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```